# Create a customized modal window without plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, modal-dialog

I have created customized modal window(without plugin) to stop the user to
interact with the UI temporarily. Here is code:
I have created some html code in the file.

```
 <div id="modalWindow" style="display:none; visibility:hidden" class="black"> 
 </div>
```

And here are the css setting:

```
black{                                                                       
    display: none;                                                          
    position: absolute;                                                                    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;                                                               
    width: 100%;                                                          
    height: 100%;                                                           
    background-color: black;                                                 
    z-index:1;                                                              
}
```

Also, I created some js function to call it dynamically.

```
function modal(){                                                            
    showModalWindow();                                                       
    setTimeout(hideModalWindow, 2000);                                       
 }                                                                           

function showModalWindow() {                                                 
     document.getElementById("modalWindow").style.display = "block";         
     document.getElementById("modalWindow").style.visibility = "visible";    
 }                                                                           

function hideModalWindow() {                                                 
     document.getElementById("modalWindow").style.display = "none";          
     document.getElementById("modalWindow").style.visibility = "hidden";     
 }
```

But when I call modal(), the black screen(modal) just vanishes soon. It's expected
to last for 2 seconds, I thought.
Please correct my mistake and provide a great alternative approach. (No plugin, thanks)

Comment: your code is working fine in here http://jsfiddle.net/b9dmpkm2/

Comment: No, it's not fine. The script in put on the server and when I call `modal()`, it often can last for 2(s). I mean it seems to work normally on local test but not for server

Comment: javascript always executes on browser, it has nothing to do with your server, unless you are using nodejs

Comment: can you share server url

Comment: Oh... I'm coding at the embedded system...